# Как правильно сверстать такой блок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как правильно сверстать такой блок только на HTML и CSS не используя Bootstrap и т.п.? Затруднение больше вызывает как сделать черту между блоками и соблюсти все отступы и выравнивания как в примере.
Сам верстку только учу, и захотел скопировать данный сайт. Вот на этом блоке просто застрял.
Ссылка на сам [сайт](https://previews.aspirity.com/danny/)
[image: Пример]

Comment: В Хроме нажми F12, там есть инструменты для исследования элементов. Здесь достаточно внутренним элементам указать width:50% и position:relative

Comment: На сайте этот блок свёрстан с помощью bootstrap, а автор вопроса просит без bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю воспользоваться flexbox и всю сетку строить на нём

**Раверните пример на всю страницу а браузер сожмите до предела**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.items {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.item1 {
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item2 {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item2-outer {
  width: 49%;
  margin: 2px;
}

.item1 h3,
.item2-outer h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.item1 p,
.item2-outer p {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 90%;
}

.item2-outer:nth-child(1),
.item2-outer:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .item2-outer:nth-child(1),
  .item2-outer:nth-child(2) {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .item1,
  .item2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .item2-outer {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 540px) {
  .items {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .item1-top,
  .item1-bottom {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  h3 {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 4px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  svg {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class="items">
  <div class="item1">
    <div class="item1-top">
      <h3>Scills</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, dolore? Odio sit cupiditate veritatis placeat quibusdam impedit, corrupti saepe adipisci.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item1-bottom">
      <svg viewBox=" 0 0 200 50" width="100px">
        <g><path d="M0,0 20,20 40,0 60,20 80,0 100,20 120,0 140,20"  fill="none" stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="3"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(0,20)">
          <path d="M0,0 20,20 40,0 60,20 80,0 100,20 120,0 140,20"  fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
    <div class="item2-outer">
      <h3>web development</h3>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, dolore? Odio sit cupiditate veritatis placeat quibusdam impedit, corrupti saepe adipisci.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item2-outer">
      <h3>ui/ux design</h3>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, dolore? Odio sit cupiditate veritatis placeat quibusdam impedit, corrupti saepe adipisci.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item2-outer">
      <h3>Frontend development</h3>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, dolore? Odio sit cupiditate veritatis placeat quibusdam impedit, corrupti saepe adipisci.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item2-outer">
      <h3>Cansalding & seo audit</h3>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta, dolore? Odio sit cupiditate veritatis placeat quibusdam impedit, corrupti saepe adipisci.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: так же как и хроме ! нормально

Answer (score 0):

Вот html:

```html
<body>
<div class="place">
  <div class="container1">
  <div class="box1">
   <h1>Skills<span>.</span></h1>
   <p>I am inspired by creating great work with people who are as passionate as I am about building something awesome.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
    <h1>Web Development</h1>
                <p>Javascript, Coffeescript, JAVA, Python, PHP, Go, Node.js, MongoDB, Redis, PostgreSQL, WebStorm.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box3">
       <h1>UI\UX Design</h1>
                <p>Photoshop, Illustrator, Sketch, Axure, XMind, Prototyping, Wireframing, User Research, Usability Testing.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box4">
       <h1>Frontend Development</h1>
        <p>HTML, CSS, LESS, SASS, Bootstrap, Wordpress, Drupal, Phonegap / Cordova, Ionic, Foundation, Angular.js.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="box5">
     <h1>Consulting & SEO Audit</h1>
              <p>Screaming Frog, Woorank, Raventools, Semrush, Moz, WebCEO, Google Analytics, ChartBeat, CrazyEgg.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

вот css:

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .place {
   width: 100%;
   height: 625px;
  }

  .container1 {
   height: 300px;
   width: 100%;
   font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 200;
   border-top: 1px solid darkgrey;
   border-bottom: 1px solid darkgrey;
   margin-top: 1%;
   padding-top:2%;
  }

  .container1 .box1 {
   float: left;
   width: 450px;
   height: 300px;
   font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
   margin-top: 1%;
   position: relative;
   padding-left: 1%;
  }

  .container1 .box1 p {
   padding-top: 10px;
  }

  .container1 .box1 span {
   font-style: bold;
   color: purple;
   font-size: 40px;
   padding: 1%;
  }

  .container1  .box2 , .box3 , .box4 , .box5{
   float: right;
   width: 400px;
   height: 120px;
   margin: 1%;
  }

  .container1 .box2 , .container1 .box3 {
   border-bottom: 1px solid darkgrey;
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно добавлять HTML и CSS одним блоком кода.

Comment: @АлексейШиманович, учту это.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно вот так:

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

section {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-around;
 height: 330px;
}

.top,
.bottom {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
}

.top > div {
 padding-bottom: 50px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.bottom {
    margin-top: 50px;
}


h2 {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.first,
.second {
 width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<section>
   <div class="top">
    <div class="first">
     <h2>Web Development</h2>
     <div class="descr">Javascript, Coffeescript, JAVA, Python, PHP, Go, Node.js, MongoDB, Redis, PostgreSQL, WebStorm.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="second">
     <h2>UI\UX Design</h2>
     <div class="descr">Photoshop, Illustrator, Sketch, Axure, XMind, Prototyping, Wireframing, User Research, Usability Testing.</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="bottom">
    <div class="first">
     <h2>Frontend Development</h2>
     <div class="descr">HTML, CSS, LESS, SASS, Bootstrap, Wordpress, Drupal, Phonegap / Cordova, Ionic, Foundation, Angular.js.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="second">
     <h2>Consulting & SEO Audit</h2>
     <div class="descr">Screaming Frog, Woorank, Raventools, Semrush, Moz, WebCEO, Google Analytics, ChartBeat, CrazyEgg.</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
```

Также если нужно будет делать адаптивную верстку, достаточно будет добавить для `.top` и `.bottom` `display: block;` и убрать `margin-top: 50px;` у `.bottom`.

Если надо, вот линия:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 105 20" style="enable-background:new 0 0 105 20;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:none;stroke:#0D5ED7;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g>
 <g>
  <polyline class="st0" points="2.5,5 16.8,15 31.1,5 45.3,15 59.6,5 73.9,15 88.2,5 102.5,15   "/>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Она слегка другого цвета, так как в атрибутике у неё не было указанно `fill`, но это можно исправить в её коде.

Comment: если ещё и волну сделаете - будет ваще атас

Comment: Линия с сайта готова

Comment: ну блин - не острую же - там же она закруглённая

Comment: вот svg если так svg хотел - https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/NWGgwqp